# How to add repository lauchpad?

Tags: repository, launchpad

I found the following package:
[xserver-xorg-input-tslib 0.0.6-7build4 (armhf binary) in ubuntu trusty](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/144156375/xserver-xorg-input-tslib_0.0.6-7build4_armhf.deb)
in the launchpad.net site: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/armhf/xserver-xorg-input-tslib/0.0.6-7build4

Is it possible to install the package using a repository?